# Unable to install dmetar

Tags: r

I am trying to install dmetar. 
I am trying to follow the recommendations on https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/dmetar.html

> R.Version()$version.string
>   [1] "R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)

Then I type:
devtools::install_github("MathiasHarrer/dmetar")

I get this warning message:

Skipping install of 'dmetar' from a github remote, the SHA1 (e40caca4) has not changed since last install.
  Use `force = TRUE` to force installation

HOW DO I FORCE THE INSTALLATION?

then I try to look, if it is already installed 
library("dmetar")

I get: 
Fejl: package or namespace load failed for ‘dmetar’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 der er ingen pakke med navn ‘lme4’

Comment: Did you try any other resource for installing ?

Comment: There's is some issue with lme4 (I am guessing from swedish i know =p ), can you try upgrading lme4 first?